# Objective-C - Callback when keyboard is off screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, callback, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I'm sliding the keyboard off screen by doing this:

```
-(void)methodA {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

I listen to `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` to be notified when the keyboard is hidden, here is the selector for the notification:

```
- (void)keyboardHidden:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // What to do here?
}
```

Now in methodA I would like to be informed when the keyboard has been hidden so I can start doing another task, my pseudo code looks like this:

```
-(void)methodA {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    wait until keyboardHidden = YES
    if(keyboardHidden) {
        // code
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still need to write code under `-(void)methodA` do

```
-(void)methodA
{
   if(!isKeyBoarHidden){
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
   }
   else{
        //code here
   }
}

- (void)keyboardHidden:(NSNotification *)notification {
      isKeyBoarHidden = YES;
      [self methodA];
}
```

sometime it may be helpful if we have some local variables inside `methodA` and we dont need to make variables global.

Answer (score 0):

Well:

```
-(void)methodA
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}


- (void)keyboardHidden:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //Keyboard is Hidden
    // code
}
```

I think it makes more sense. Still a block solution might be viable.